# dropbox linux: Where can I find the user linked to my linux box

Tags: linux, dropbox, debian-wheezy

I've set up several dropbox account and I can't remember which dropbox user I used for a specific linux box. I there a way on the linux to find which user is connected with ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're running Dropbox on a desktop:

- From the notification area/system tray on the Linux box in question, right click the Dropbox icon
- Click the **Account** tab
- Your account should be listed towards the bottom as **My Name (myemail@domain.com)**

Answer (score 0):

Sign into your Dropbox account on the web, and go to Settings -> security as explained here:

https://www.dropbox.com/help/25/en

You can look at your linked computers, and find the right one.